# Does significant-location change service work for WiFi spots?

Tags: ios, location, core-location

My question is, can significant-change location service update the location while switching from one wifi spot/basestation to another?

I know it works well for radio towers.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my answer since I answered the wrong thing.

Since I don't have enough points to clarify your question as a comment I will do so in this "answer" instead for future readers.

So the question isn't if the significant-change service works with WiFi alone (which it doesn't Apple require a device with "cellular radio" for some reason) but if a change in the nearby WiFi list itself in enough to trigger a location update.